# EC2 Instance giving better output than ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have cluster of 3 EC2 instances. Single EC2 instance is able to server aroung 500 user load on application. But when same EC2 instnace is put in ELB is not even serving for 250 users. We drilled more & put below configuration at different end.

1. Optimized code to respond in less time.
2. ELB is set with 300 sec timeout for all responses & healthy.unhealthy checks.
3. Apache on EC2 is set with 600 as timeout value & keep alive it set true.
4. ELB is routing request in equal distribution logic.

Every time we hit with higher load(500 on cluster) we are getting end up getting some failures with 504 bad gateway timeout error. Kindly help with solution to get more optimial output.

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is your webservers and not a backend service like a database?

Comment: Yes, DB Utilization is under control. We even tried putting timeouts but it is not useful.

Comment: We have 504 gateway timeout error correcting main description.

Comment: Where is the 504 error coming from? is it an ELB 504 error or a backend 504 error?

Additionally, not sure which instance type you are using (e.g. T2 has busrtable CPU and Network performance) but make sure to check the following:
- Network throttling on EC2
- Disk (EBS) performance ( check the I/O response times )
- Memory usage on EC2